# How to downmix stereo output to mono on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, conversion, mono, stereo

Let's just open and close this:

Is there a built in way to downmix all stereo output to mono on Mac OS X?

Comment: Due to my low rep, I won't be able to self answer this until tomorrow. The answer is: http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-system-mac-software/270024-forcing-mono-audio.html#post1514096

Comment: This seems appropriate here, but could also be appropriate over at Audio-Video production. Can an answer be linked without being moved? Mods?

Comment: @Obscure Nope, not really possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

---

I tried modifying the setting in `com.apple.universalaccess.plist`, but couldn't get it to take effect:

```
f=~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess
sudo defaults write $f stereoAsMono -bool true
sudo chown $USER $f.plist
```

---

An AppleScript that toggles the preference:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Hearing" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 2 of tab group 1 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's an option to enable mono conversion under Universal Access.

> System Preferences > Universal Access > Hearing > Play Stereo as Mono.

[image: Stereo to mono downmix under Universal Access options on Max OS X 10.8]

Found the answer [here](http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-system-mac-software/270024-forcing-mono-audio.html#post1514096).

**EDIT 2014-05-25:** As explained in [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14426), the stereo to mono downmix option can be found under Accessabilty on **Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks**.

> System Preferences > Accessibility > Hearing > Audio > Play stereo audio as mono

[image: Stereo to mono downmix option under Accessability settings pane on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks]

**Under iOS 7.1 on the iPhone and iPad**, stereo to [mono conversion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5018) can be enabled here:

> Settings > General > Accessibility > Hearing > Mono Audio

Comment: Ok after a page reload it turns out Lri apparently posted basically the same answer and then some. I'm going to accept his answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to include instructions for enabling mono audio on OS X 10.9 Mavericks and iOS. As someone who occasionally has struggled with semi broken headphones and weird PA systems for important presentations, I know I'd be delighted to find instructions for enabling stereo to mono downmixing on all Apple gadgets on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

(Forgive me for digging up an old post...)

On Mac Os X Yosemite (maybe on Mavericks too), the Accessibility window is slightly different and the Applescript posted above doesn't work. Here's the same one with a slight modification:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Hearing" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    click checkbox 2 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Save it as an app and pop it into your dock for one-click monofying bliss!

Comment: Cool. Alternately, I made an app to toggle the setting. It's called "Mono Menulet" http://charlesism.com/monomenulet.html